# Application Insights SDK agent in Linux Docker container?

Tags: docker, azure-application-insights

I'm deploying an Asp.Net Core service hosted by Kestrel in a Linux container.  I was hoping to take advantage of the App Insights SDK agent monitoring for calls to dependencies, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies.

There are instructions for IIS and Azure...but I can't find any way to do this in a Linux container.  Has anyone gotten this working?  Am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

The status monitor/extension agent is a set of IIS configuration things and  plugin into the .net profiler.

i don't think that's supported by .net core yet, so it won't work on docker + linux.

from the system requirements section on the page you linked:

> ### System Requirements
>
> OS support for Application Insights Status Monitor on Server:
>
> - Windows Server 2008
> - Windows Server 2008 R2
> - Windows Server 2012
> - Windows server 2012 R2
> - Windows Server 2016
>
> with latest SP and .NET Framework 4.5
>
> On the client side: Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10, again with .NET Framework 4.5
>
> IIS support is: IIS 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5 (IIS is required)